# Uninstall Windows

Tags: windows, uninstall

I have a question about removing windows. I installed Ubuntu from the windows desktop because the live cd did not work. How can I delete Windows without removing Ubuntu?

Comment: Have you tried installing from a bootable USB?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it. Since you installed Ubuntu "from" Windows, you did a WUBI installation. That means that your Ubuntu image and files are inside Windows.

If you try, by any means, to format Windows partition, or whatever, your Ubuntu will be gone as well.